# I would like my sqlite DB to have preloaded information that is available to the app in android

Tags: sqlite, kotlin

Im trying to build "Word of the day" kind of app. This notifies the user at a specified time of the day. My problem is getting info in the sqlite DB. How do i ensure this is populated with all the words their meanings etc. I dont want to go on the internet & download from a site. I would rather prepopulate the DB & have the app just run on the mobile, even if there is no internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out.
Created a DB externally & used the following code to copy it into the databases folder.

```
private fun copyDB(context: Context){
    close()
    val path=appDataPath+dbSubPath
    if(!File(path).exists())
    {
        val file=File(path)
        with(file) {
            parentFile?.mkdirs()
            createNewFile()
        }
    }
    val ipStream=context.assets.open(db_Name)
    val opStream=FileOutputStream(appDataPath+dbSubPath)
    opStream.write(ipStream.readBytes())
    writableDatabase.close()
}
```